# Building R packages - using environment variables in DESCRIPTION file?

Tags: r

At our site, we have a large amount of custom R code that is used to build a set of packages for internal use and distribution to our R users.  We try to maintain the entire library in a versioning scheme so that the version numbers and the date are the same.  The problem is that we've gotten to the point where the number of packages is substantial enough that manual modification of the DESCRIPTION file and the package .Rd file is very time consuming, and it would be nice to automate these pieces.

We could write a pre-script that goes through the full set of files and writes the current data and version number.  This could be done with out a lot of pain, but it would modify our current build chain and we would have to adapt the various steps.

Is there a way that this can be done without having to do a pre-build file modification step?  In other words, can the DESCRIPTION file and the .Rd file contain something akin to an environment variable that will be substituted with the current information when called upon by R CMD build ?

Comment: Maybe consider using Makefiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use environment variables as R, when running `R CMD build ...` or `R CMD INSTALL ...`, sees the file as fixed.

But the *no problem that cannot be fixed by another layer of indirection* saying remains true.  Your R source code could simply be files within another layer in which you text substitution according to some pattern.  If you like `autoconf`, you could just have `DESCRIPTION.in` and have a configure script query the environment variables, or a meta-config file or database, or something else, and have that written out. Similarly you could have a `sed` or `perl` or `python` or `R` or ... script doing the textual substitution.

I used to let svn fill in the argument to `Date:` in DESCRIPTION, and also encoded revision numbers in an included header file.  It's all scriptable to your heart's content.